# Error en la base de datos couchdb, no estoy autorizado para acceder

Tags: base-de-datos, couchdb

Estoy intentando acceder a la base de datos de couchdb con el comando curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/channel_cc3

pero me da el siguiente error:

`{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"you are not authorized to access this db."}`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionar esto?

Comment: no estas enviando tu usuario y tu contraseña de usuario

Comment: curl -X put http://username:password@localhost/

Comment: en el "@localhost", no hace falta especificar el puerto?
el usuario y la contraseña digo yo que serán los que he puesto yo para crear la base de datos no?

Answer (score 0):

Es que le tienes que pasar en la petición `GET` el usuario y la contraseña para realizar el proceso de autenticación, la petición sería algo así:

```
http://usuario:clave@127.0.0.1:5984/channel_cc3
```